# Displaying current system date and time

Tags: php, yii2

How do I show my current system (PC) time on a form

Right now I'm currently using a datetimepicker, I wanna try when I'm going to create something in a form the "time_start" will automatically get the time that is being used on my PC.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'time_start')->widget(
    DateTimePicker::className(), [
        'options'       => [ 'placeholder' => 'Render Time' ],
        'pluginOptions' => [ 'autoclose' => true, ]
    ]
); ?>
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server not your pc.  It will use the server time unless you tell it differently. You will have to send the time from the pc to the the php script. It can then work out the time to use in the 'date picker'

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value to  $model->time_start  directly in your controller before  call the render  ..

so you problem can be managed  in controllerAction using php functin for assign the value you need eg in actionCreate

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new MyModel();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        //  assign the the date and time of the server that the code runs on.
        $model->time_start =  date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

or if you need  an specific timezone

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new MyModel();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        //  assign the the date and time of the server that the code runs on.
        //  
        $my_date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York') );

        $model->time_start =   $my_date;
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine, it displays the right date but not the time? I think its because of the timezone, how do I change my timezone

Comment: I figure it out now that I don't need to change the timezone because it automatically gets the current system date and time from the server, my problem is it doesn't show the right time when I'm creating the form but if the form has been already created it displays the right time lol I don't why its so confusing. Anyways thanks for the help it really helped me alot

Comment: explain better  .. you comment about the "my problem is it doesn't show the right time when I'm creating the form but if the form has been already created it displays the right time" is not clear  ..